# Switch statement in Java

Tags: java

Basically I need to take a letter A-Z and convert it to Leek(a combo of sign,#,letter that look like the A-Z characters. I'm only allow to use switch statements (switch,case,breaks) also I have to use the .next().charAt(0) method.

When I try to compile my program it comes up with multiple error all reading "can not find symbol" pointing at the a-z character I used in the case statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dlin_Leet
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        char character;//input by user
        String Leet;

        System.out.print("Enter character to convert:");
        String Leet = input.next();
        char character = Leet.charAt(0);

        switch (character)
        {
            case a: Leet = "4";
                break;
            case b: Leet = "I3";
                break;
            case c: Leet = "[";
                break;
            case d: Leet = ")";
                break;
            case e: Leet = "3";
                break;
            case f: Leet = "|=";
                break;
            case g: Leet = "&";
                break;
            case h: Leet = "#";
                break;
            case i: Leet = "1";
                break;
            case j: Leet = "J";
                break;
            case k: Leet = "|<";
                break;
            case l: Leet = "1";

             }
        System.out.println(Leet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case statement using `char` (which means single quote), it should be something like

```
 switch (character)
            {
                case 'a': Leet = "4";
                    break;
                case 'b': Leet = "I3";
                    break;
             .........
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

The character constants must be in into apostraphs:

`case 'a':`  instead of `case a:`

Fix your code and I hope this is the only syntax error you have.

Answer (score 3):

Also
 - You are declaring variable "Leet" and "character" twice in the same block( Duplicate local variable)

Answer (score 0):

your case should be a char like case 'a'

```
 switch(character) 

 {
    case 'a':
       //do your stuff
    }
```

and also you are declaring leet(String variable twice). just declare it one and use the same variable when you get input from the scanner

Answer (score 0):

Using strings in switch case can only be used if you using JDK7 and even then you will have to have the values in quotes.
Like

```
case "a":
```

Comment: He's switching over character.. It should be 'a'. That is perfectly valid in Java 6 also.